# Is the Black Blood Hunter's Animal Aspect's natural armor bonus permanent or temporary?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

The [Black Blood Hunter](http://realmshelps.net/cgi-bin/prestige2.pl?class=Black_Blood_Hunter)'s ability called Animal Aspect states:

> Starting at 2nd level, a black blood hunter gains the ability to take on limited characteristics of his [animal form](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lycanthrope.htm) while remaining in his [humanoid](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#humanoidType) form. Once per day, he can gain the Strength, Dexterity, or Constitution of his animal form without actually adopting that shape. **In addition, his [natural armor](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#naturalarmorbonus) increases by +2.** All these changes last for 1 minute per black blood hunter level. The black blood hunter can use this ability twice per day at 4th level, three times at 6th level, four times at 8th level, and five times at 10th level.

---

The words "in addition" are confusing me. Is it a permanent bonus or is it only during the 1 minute per black blood hunter level?

The reason for my confusion - there are other class features and feats that give a +X Y/day, and +Z as a litle kicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's a Dependent Sentence**

The phrasing of the sentence and its placement relative to the description of the ability indicates that it lasts for one minute per level, *in addition* to the previously-mentioned effect. This is further reinforced by the statement "all these changes" before the description of the ability's duration. To be permanent, the sentence would need to be placed outside, typically *after*, the description of the duration.